# send message and callback/promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, promise

I got a problem and can`t handle with it for a lot of time.

1. callback

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
if (request.event === 'login') {
    socket.emit('login', request.data, (res, reply) => {
        console.log(sendResponse);
        sendResponse(1);
    });
}
return true;
});
```

view script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            event: 'login',
            data: hash.toString()
        }, (res) => {
            alert(1);
        });
```

2. with promise

background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
   if (request.event === 'login') {
      socket.emit('login', request.data, (res, reply) => {
         return new Promise((res,rej)=>{console.log(123);res(213);});
      });
   }
});
```

view script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            event: 'login',
            data: hash.toString()
        }).then((res)=>{alert(res)});
```

Problem: with callback i can`t get any parameter through response and promise just not working (btw tryed it first time).

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with callback or promise.

UPD 1: 
I mean with sendResponse(1) i`ll get res = undefined in callback.
UPD 2:
also tryed to put return true in if statement.

Comment: If you can't get something working with callbacks, transforming to Promises won't magically make it work.  It's a bit unclear what your asking and what problem your trying to solve, what does -> `i can't get any parameter through response` mean,. what parameters?, what response?, and what is `sendResponse`? etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm but i have return true and it still not working. Tryed put it in if statement too.

Comment: Oopsie, sorry...

Comment: Maybe you've included the popup script as a content script and you're looking at the wrong devtools (of the web page) instead of the popup's, which is accessible by rightclicking the popup, then clicking "inspect".